# HttpClient.get does not return observable from Wiki API

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, mediawiki, ionic4

I'm trying to get some text from specific Wikipedia pages but I cannot access to it. I'm trying to understand how it works and I do not know why it still doesn't, cause no error is given.

I tried several type of URLs like this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=105sort=hot https://gyazo.com/54ee18fe654fcfe2bd5d546b44f85b5d, and it returns.
I suspect it has something to do with CORS but have no idea how it works.

servicio.service.ts code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ServicioService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('service working!');
    }

    goWiki(userInput): Observable<any>{
        console.log('goWiki working!');
      //let url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=105sort=hot';
        return this.http.get('https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch='+ userInput +'&utf8=&format=json',);
    } //took that link from this: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&meta=siteinfo&siprop=magicwords>

}
...
```

home.page.ts

```
import { ServicioService } from '../servicio.service';
...
constructor(
    navcntrlr: NavController,
    private alertcontroller: AlertController, 
    public servicio: ServicioService) { }

    userInput = 'alcasser';


    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.search();
    }

    search(){
      console.log("henllo xd");
      const hola = this.servicio.goWiki(this.userInput).
      subscribe((response) => {
       console.log(response);
       });
    }
...
```

I hope to get an observable json to be able to play with it and take from it the info I need.

Comment: what do you see if you add error call back to your subscribe method ?

Comment: what errors do you have in the console? (including cors warnings)

Comment: I suggest you use `FormControl` for your user input (if its an input element) and subscribe to it, within the subscription then call your `this.servicio.goWiki` function and subscribe to it, your userInput property is `null` or `undefined` and the service probably returns a `404` or `500`.

Comment: @RezaRahmati [this error](https://gyazo.com/a48ae770c410c55c9d20bddda7b52072) appears.

Comment: @david [this error](https://gyazo.com/a48ae770c410c55c9d20bddda7b52072) appears.

Comment: It's just a CORS error. Use a proxy server to bypass that restriction

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.userInput` is `null`. When you go to `https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=&utf8=&format=json` (this is the url it will try to call), you will see an error

```
{"error":{"code":"nosrsearch","info":"The \"srsearch\" parameter must be set.","*":"See https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."},"servedby":"mw1340"}
```

Try setting `this.userInput` before your call and try again.

```
    search(){
      console.log("henllo xd");
      this.userInput = 'test'; // THIS SETS USERINPUT TO 'TEST'
      const hola = this.servicio.goWiki(this.userInput).
      subscribe((response) => {
       console.log(response);
       });
    }
```

Comment: I didn't add the code but **this.userInput** is initiated in other part of the code.
And [this error](https://gyazo.com/a48ae770c410c55c9d20bddda7b52072) appears.

Comment: try this `this.http.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch'+ userInput +'&utf8=&format=json&origin=*').subscribe((response) => {` note the last part `&origin=*` in your goWiki function.

Answer (score 0):

When I use their API I get a CORS ERROR too.

I'm able to access their API in the browser
[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=usa&format=jso](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=usa&format=json)n

Here is a quick example i put using your code and passing an actual value to the API, using REACTIVE forms.

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormControl,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchForm:FormGroup;
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('service working!');
    }

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      'searchInput': new FormControl(null),
      });
  }

  onSubmit():void {
    console.log(this.searchForm.value.searchInput);
    this.goWiki(this.searchForm.value.searchInput)
  }

    goWiki(userInput):void{
        console.log('goWiki working!');
        this.http.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch'+ userInput +'&utf8=&format=json').subscribe((response) => {
       console.log(response);
       });
    } 
}
```